How to validate that you have added @CacheEvict to all the methods that would update a cached value
I have a query in my Spring Boot 3.2 code that is exspensive to run and I would like to cache the value. The query is taking a few component parts and then counting them to return a single value.
For example, I have a blogging platform and I want to know the number of times a user has commented under a specific tag and show this in a table.
The conditions I would want to evict under would be:

the user creates a new comment
the user deletes a comment
a blog post is deleted
a blog post is updated (either adding or removing a tag)

As the use case has more dependencies it gets harder to ensure that all the elements are being tracked.
I would like to know if there is a way to:

invert the evict, 'My cache should be evicted when these things are updated' This would at least keep the logic in one place?
can you validate/test that a cache gets evicted so that if there are new ways for something to be changed (new methods or dependencies to the query) they are reported rather than waiting for a bug report?
how is this type of cache management usually handled, all the examples I have found online so far have been simplistic.


To centralize the logic, create an event listener that would handle the cache eviction.
If you're using Spring Data JPA, then hook into the entity lifecycle events to publish an event to trigger the listener.
If not using Spring Data JPA, then could still use the same concept, but would have to implement yourself with the publisher being invoked somewhere within the data layer.
A unit test could verify the publisher was invoked, but it would still be up to you to ensure the publisher was added to the new dependency.

If one is using JPA you are better of using the 2nd level caching capabilities of the JPA provider.

Curious if L2 would work with a distributed cache? edit: found an example using Redis.
